# C Programming Writing to registry isn't working? Error at RegSetValueEX

Tags: c, windows, registry, registerstartupscript

Trying to write my programme into the windows registry but my code tells me there is an error when doing the `RegSetValueEX()`. I have administrative access. I can't see whats wrong at all and I've been staring at MSDN pages on REG all day.

```
int StartupKey()
{
    int StartupKey;
    long RegOpenResult, result_write;
    const char *FilePath[]= "C:\\Windows\\security\\BensKlog.exe";
    LPCSTR Klog = "BensKLOG";

    HKEY hkey;
    printf("Opening Key...\n");
    RegOpenResult = RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,"SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", 0, KEY_ALL_ACCESS, &hkey);
    if(RegOpenResult != ERROR_SUCCESS) {
    if(RegOpenResult  == ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND) {
        printf("Not found\n");
    } else {
        printf("Error Opening Key\n");
    }
  } else {
    printf("SUCCESS!!!\n");
  }
    StartupKey=RegCreateKey(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,"SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run",&hkey);

    printf("Writing Value named Klog\n");
    result_write = RegSetValueEx((HKEY)hkey,Klog,0,REG_SZ,(BYTE *)FilePath,strlen(FilePath));
    if(result_write != ERROR_SUCCESS) {
    printf("Error Writing Value\n");
  } else {
    printf("SUCCESS!!!\n");
  }
    RegCloseKey(hkey);
  }
```

Comment: "my code tells me there is an error".  That's because it is *bad code*.  It doesn't tell what **specific** error occurred.  So you just don't know why it doesn't work.

Comment: I'm aware it's a simple code, what are the error code returns for the registry? Instead of just error_success. So I can retrieve why the error is occurring

Comment: If you want to know what an error code means then you can ask that question.  Don't expect anybody to give you an exhaustive list of all possible error codes, that's already widely available.  Just google "Windows error codes" and the first hit gives you that list.

Comment: I never asked for an exhaustive list, you speak of a 'specific' error occurrence. Well how do I find the specific error. Cause I've googled windows registry errors and wasn't given a exhaustive list

Answer (score 1):

```
const char *FilePath[]= "C:\\Windows\\security\\BensKlog.exe";
```

Use either:

```
const char FilePath[] = "C:\\Windows\\security\\BensKlog.exe";
```

or

```
const char *FilePath = "C:\\Windows\\security\\BensKlog.exe";
```

but don't mix them (your code defines an array of const char pointers instead of one pointer).

(Might not be the only error though)

Answer (score 0):

Spoke to a lecturer at my university, showed him
My code he claims I need to run on an Administrator account, turns out my
User on my laptop wasn't the admin(which I thought it was) will check if it works when I'm home and update